# Examples for Alexander's Trick (radial extension)

Tags: geometry, differential-topology

I'm interested in examples regarding the [Alexander's Trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander%27s_trick). Can someone give an example where a diffeomorphism $f:S^{n-1}\rightarrow S^{n-1}$ extends to a diffeomorphism $D^n\rightarrow D^n$ and then another example where $f$ only extends to a homeomorphism?

Comment: Any linear diffeomorphism extends to a diffeomorphism of the ball. The first (known) example of a diffeomorphism of the sphere that does not extend to one in the ball is on $S^6$.

Comment: Where can I find the example with the $S^6$?

Comment: Abstractly: let $\Gamma_n$ be the quotient group of diffeomorphisms of $S^n$ modulo those that extend to the ball $B^{n+1}$. For $n \geq 5$, you can prove that $\Gamma_n = \Theta_{n+1}$, where $\Theta_n$ denotes the group of oriented exotic spheres in $n$ dimensions. (Pick two copies of the ball and glue them together by such an exotic diffeomorphism along the boundary.) So take one of Milnor's examples of exotic 7-spheres and pick the corresponding diffeomorphism. (I should probably just write an answer, though I'm not sure if this is really what your goal is to understand.)